# CompletionException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Quarkus)

Tags: java, multithreading, quarkus

I will try to sumary my problem

I have a REST service which do a process 4 times. Each iteration does not depend on the previous one, so I want to do this 4 iterations in parallel.

I'm using Java in Quarkus with MicroProfile and Hibernate OMR (and more stuff like Lombok)

**Problem:**
I think that I get my goal, but, 1/3 times I call the REST service, its fail, but the other 2/3 works fine.

When it fail, I get this **exception**:

```
2020-08-05 13:06:37,353 WARN  [com.arj.ats.arjuna] (executor-thread-2) ARJUNA012127: TwoPhaseCoordinator.afterCompletion - returned failure for SynchronizationImple< 0:ffffc0a832eb:efa4:5f2a92b3:53, io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.entitymanager.TransactionScopedEntityManager$1@549ed75a >
2020-08-05 13:06:37,353 WARN  [org.hib.res.tra.bac.jta.int.syn.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorTrackingImpl] (executor-thread-2) HHH000451: Transaction afterCompletion called by a background thread; delaying afterCompletion processing until the original thread can handle it. [status=4]
2020-08-05 13:06:37,354 ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (executor-thread-2) HTTP Request to /arbol/v1/estructura/generar-estructura failed, error id: 58aaf095-1659-4050-8ef9-92aeffa5164b-4: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:106)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:372)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:216)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:515)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:259)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:160)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:362)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:163)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:245)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:132)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.access$000(VertxRequestHandler.java:37)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:94)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.CleanableExecutor$CleaningRunnable.run(CleanableExecutor.java:231)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2046)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1578)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1766)
        at io.smallrye.context.SmallRyeThreadContext$ContextualRunnable.run(SmallRyeThreadContext.java:56)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:145)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:81)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:50)
        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1325)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1405)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1565)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533)
        at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
        at es.metadata.repository.UtRepository.obtenerUts(UtRepository.java:46)
        at es.metadata.repository.UtRepository_Subclass.obtenerUts$$superaccessor3(UtRepository_Subclass.zig:844)
        at es.metadata.repository.UtRepository_Subclass$$function$$3.apply(UtRepository_Subclass$$function$$3.zig:33)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInCallerTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:244)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorSupports.doIntercept(TransactionalInterceptorSupports.java:34)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:53)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorSupports.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorSupports.java:26)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorSupports_Bean.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorSupports_Bean.zig:339)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
        at es.metadata.repository.UtRepository_Subclass.obtenerUts(UtRepository_Subclass.zig:801)
        at es.metadata.repository.UtRepository_ClientProxy.obtenerUts(UtRepository_ClientProxy.zig:398)
        at es.metadata.service.UtService.obtenerTodas(UtService.java:23)
        at es.metadata.service.UtService_ClientProxy.obtenerTodas(UtService_ClientProxy.zig:315)
        at es.metadata.service.EstructuraArbolService.generarEstructuraEmpresaUnica(EstructuraArbolService.java:120)
        at es.metadata.service.EstructuraArbolService_Subclass.generarEstructuraEmpresaUnica$$superaccessor14(EstructuraArbolService_Subclass.zig:2836)
        at es.metadata.service.EstructuraArbolService_Subclass$$function$$14.apply(EstructuraArbolService_Subclass$$function$$14.zig:47)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ActivateRequestContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(ActivateRequestContextInterceptor.java:20)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ActivateRequestContextInterceptor_Bean.intercept(ActivateRequestContextInterceptor_Bean.zig:275)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
        at es.metadata.service.EstructuraArbolService_Subclass.generarEstructuraEmpresaUnica(EstructuraArbolService_Subclass.zig:2789)
        at es.metadata.service.EstructuraArbolService.lambda$0(EstructuraArbolService.java:73)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1764)
        ... 12 more
```

**What I have:**
I'm very lost with this exception. I 'dont know even in what layer is the problem. I don't know what it means either the NullPointerException, beacouse some times work. For me, it has no sense

Next, I'm posting parts of my code to show what I have.

**Repositories:**
All XRepository are equivalents (UtRepository, UgUtRepository...)

```
@Transactional(SUPPORTS)
public abstract class AbstractRepository<E, P> {

    private final Class<E> entityClass;

    public AbstractRepository(Class<E> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    // some queries
}
```

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class UgRepository extends AbstractRepository<Ug, Integer> {

    @Inject
    @PackagePrivate
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public UgRepository() {
        super(Ug.class);
    }

    public List<Ug> obtenerUgs(Integer idEmpresa) {
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Ug.obtenerTodos");

        query.setParameter("idEmpresa", idEmpresa);

        return ListCaster.castearLista(Ug.class, query.getResultList());
    }

    // some queries
}
```

**Entities:**
All entities are equivalents (Ut, UgUt...)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ug")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Ug.obtenerTodos", query = "SELECT ug FROM Ug ug WHERE ug.empresaPrincipal.idEmpresa = :idEmpresa")
// some queries})
@Getter
@Setter
public class Ug {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_ug", table = "ug", nullable = false)
    private Integer idUg;

    // some columns and relationships

    public Ug() {
    }
}
```

**The service that do the 4 calls to the algorithm:** (generarEstructuraEmpresaUnica)

Inside the method "generarEstructuraEmpresaUnica", I make some SELECTs to the BD and I have a recursive method. I think the problem maybe is here (in the queries to BD), because in the Exception trace you can see "UtRepository"

Also, repository shown in the exception is diferent any time. Some times is "UgRepository", other times "UtRepository", "UgUtRepository"...

```
@Inject
ManagedExecutor executor;

    @Transactional
    public JSONObject generarEstructuraEmpresas(List<EmpresaPrincipal> lista)
            throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

        JSONObject arbol = new JSONObject();
        List<CompletableFuture<JSONObject>> listaArboles = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            final Integer posLista = i;

            CompletableFuture<JSONObject> future = CompletableFuture
                    .supplyAsync(() -> generarEstructuraEmpresaUnica(lista.get(posLista), posLista + 1,
                            lista.size() == 1 ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE), executor);

            listaArboles.add(future);
        }

        CompletableFuture<Void> completationList = CompletableFuture
                .allOf(listaArboles.toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new));
        CompletableFuture<List<JSONObject>> completationListJSON = completationList
                .thenApply(avoid -> listaArboles.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.toList()));

        arbol.put("Arbol", completationListJSON.join());

        return arbol;
    }
```

If you need more info tell me. I don't want to ask a huge question

Comment: Something in `generarEstructuraEmpresaUnica` is throwing NPE, apparently when interacting with hibernate.